# Cannot execute select statement in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have an action that should select a row from a table using the id:

```
@RequestMapping("/test/{userId}")
@ResponseBody
public void testUserSettings(@DestinationVariable Integer userId){
    System.out.println("test");
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select us.settings from UserSettings us"
            + " where us.userId = :userId");
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        query.setParameter("userId", userId);
        query.executeUpdate();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

It invokes the method because "test" is printed. The problem is in the statement. For some reason I get the following output in the console:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for select queries [select us.settings from com.musala.ving.entities.UserSettings us where us.userId = :userId]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.errorIfSelect(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:324)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:379)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1286)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:118)
at com.musala.ving.controllers.UserSettingsController.testUserSettings(UserSettingsController.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Show us your UserSettings entity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling `query.executeUpdate();` for a `select` query. Try using `query.list()`, or `query.uniqueResult()` instead.

`query.uniqueResult()` should be used if you expect a single result.

Javadoc excerpt for [Query#list()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()):

> Return the query results as a List. If the query contains multiple results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of Object[].

Javadoc excerpt for [Query#uniqueResult()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult()):

> Convenience method to return a single instance that matches the query, or null if the query returns no results.

Also, `transaction.commit();` should not be necessary since this query doesn't update the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping("/test/{userId}")
@ResponseBody
public void testUserSettings(@DestinationVariable Integer userId){
    System.out.println("test");
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select us.settings from UserSettings us"
            + " where us.userId = :userId");
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        query.setParameter("userId", userId);
        query.list(); 
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using hibernate with hql (in conjunction with spring mvc, if that matters) and fixed the issue by doing the following:

```
String hql = "select clientId from Cart where cartId = :val" ;
        Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("val", cartId);
        //int result = query.executeUpdate(); OLD VERSION. REPLACED WITH THE LINE BELOW:
        int result = query.getFirstResult();
        return result;
```

So for me `getFirstResult()` solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

> query.executeUpdate();

you do a update of an select query !?
How the error message says... "Not supported for select queries"
use query.execute(); or what the correct method is...