# Not supported for select queries Springboot query

Tags: java, jquery, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to get the employees who started after spesific date and who earns above spesific salary.

I use these params : "startdate 2000-10-22"
"salary 10000"

But when I try I get this error :

```
"org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for select queries [Select e FROM com.example.macademiaproject.model.Employee e  where  (:startDate is NULL or e.startDate < :startDate)  AND  (:salary is NULL or e.salary > :salary) ]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for select queries [Select e FROM com.example.macademiaproject.model.Employee e  where  (:startDate is NULL or e.startDate < :startDate)  AND  (:salary is NULL or e.salary > :salary) ]",
```

Can I check the dates like "startedDate >" condition, for example is 2000/12/13 > 2001/5/8 ?. If not how am I supposed to do this ?

Repository :

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("Select e FROM Employee e  " +
        "where " +
        " (:startDate is NULL or e.startDate < :startDate) " +
        " AND " +
        " (:salary is NULL or e.salary > :salary) ")
void searchEmployees(@Param(value= "startDate")Date startDate,@Param(value = "salary") Integer salary);
```

Service :

```
 void searchEmployees(Date startDate,Integer salary);
```

ServiceImplemantation :

```
  @Override
    public void searchEmployees(Date startDate,Integer salary){
       employeeRepository.searchEmployees(startDate,salary);

    }
```

Controller :

```
    @GetMapping(path="/search")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> searchEmployees(@RequestParam("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date startDate,
                                                          @RequestParam("salary") Integer salary) {

        employeeService.searchEmployees(startDate,salary);
        return null; }
```

Comment: Why is there a `@Modifying` annotation?

Comment: Without it I'm keep getting error :  "could not extract ResultSet;" at other queries too.That's why I thought I should use it.

Answer (score 0):

how are you calling the execution of the query? This might help you hopefully: [Cannot execute select statement in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764332/cannot-execute-select-statement-in-hibernate)